# "Load Failed" on Service Worker on iOS

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari, service-worker

Currently, I'm trying to deploy my 150MB+ website as an offline PWA for iOS. This application works successfully offline on Chrome and Firefox on Android, but seems to be failing on iOS 14.1 and iOS 15. I have not gotten reports of it working successfully on any iOS version.

I am unable to get detailed console logs (having not owned an iOS device or Mac), so I have the service worker throw a popup on failure. The exact error I'm getting is

```
TypeError: Script https://frc-docs--1704.org.readthedocs.build/en/1704/sw.js load failed
```

The website and PWA is available to test, and is located [here](https://frc-docs--1704.org.readthedocs.build/en/1704/). I have attached the source code for my service worker.

```
"use strict";
// extend this to update the service worker every push
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers
let cacheName = 'js13kPWA-v1';

// todo test
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
  e.waitUntil(async function() {
    await fetch('_static/cache.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async (data) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length / 10; i++) {
            const tofetch = data.slice(i * 10, i * 10 + 10);
            await addKeys(tofetch)
          }
        })
  }());
});

// opt for a cache first response, for quickest load times
// we'll still update the page assets in the background
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  event.respondWith(async function () {
    let request_url = event.request.url;

    try {
      await addKeys([request_url]) //put in format our addKeys function expects
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error downloading from remote:", error)
    }
    
    let res = await getKey(request_url)

    console.log("Fetching:", event.request.url)
    return res;
  }());
});

let dbPromise;

async function getDB() {
  if (dbPromise) {
    return dbPromise;
  } else {
    let request = indexedDB.open("frc-docs", "1")

    dbPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        console.log("Successfully opened database!")
        resolve(event.target.result)
      }

      request.onerror = function (event) {
        console.error("Error opening database for getKey():", request.error)
        reject()
      }

      request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
        let db = event.target.result;
        db.createObjectStore("urls", { keyPath: 'key' })
      }
    });

    return dbPromise;
  }
}

async function getKey(key) {
  let db = await getDB()
  console.log("Grabbing key", key)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let transaction = db.transaction("urls").objectStore("urls");
      let request = transaction.get(key)

      request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        let res = request.result;
        console.log("Successfully retrieved result:", res)
        resolve(new Response(res.value));
      }

      request.onerror = function (event) {
        console.error("Error on retrieving blob:", key, request.error)
        reject()
      }

    } catch (ex) {
      console.error(ex.message);
      reject()
    }
  })
}

async function addKeys(datas) {
    let db = await getDB()
    return Promise.all(
      datas.map(async (data) => {
        let fetchedData = await fetch(data)
          .then(x => x.blob())
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error fetching", data)
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              reject();
            })
          })
        let transaction = db.transaction("urls", "readwrite").objectStore("urls")
        let request = transaction.put({key: data, value: fetchedData})

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          request.onsuccess = function() {
            resolve()
          }
          request.onerror = function () {
            console.log(request.error)
            reject(request.error)
          }
        });
      })
    );
    // data is already a key/value object with url/data
}
```

Comment: I have already analyzed my PWA with the Lighthouse Chrome Extension and found no major issues regarding the PWA. The PWA already works, it just doesn't work on iOS. Your comment provides no useful value.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was content blockers in Safari Extensions. In our service worker, we're utilizing Braze for push notifications. Their domain is pretty much blocked on any reputable content blocker. So, the whole service worker failed to load, even though the issue was the self.importScript.